# While doing fixpack upgrade from 8.5.5.11 to 8.5.5.17 failing with CRIMA1161E ERROR

Tags: application-server

I'm doing wepshere standard application server upgrade from 8.5.5.11 to 8.5.5.17 version with installation manager:

./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5017.20200205_1450 -repositories /opt/hotfix11 -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -acceptLicense -sP

and getting the following error:

ERROR: 'plug-in com.ibm.was.detect.offering.update.v85_8.5.0.20120308_0100' not found in ...
ERROR: 'plug-in com.ibm.was.detect.backlevel.jdk.ifix_8.0.2.20120308_0004' not found in ...

so these plugins are missing on downloaded patch for HF17, how can I resolve it, maybe somebody nows on what package or repository these plugins can be found ? I already did a try and added 8.5.5.0 repository, but there is also missing these plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Also provide the base installation media path.

./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5017.20200205_1450 -repositories /opt/hotfix11 ,/opt/WAS_base_8.5.5/ -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer -acceptLicense -sP

this will resolved your problem